# Youtube fullscreen using gallery

Tags: android, video, youtube

In my webview i cant play youtube videos in fullscreen. Also many users sent me bug reports.
What i want to do is to open youtube video in fullscreen using gallery but i do not know what code should i use.

My code:

```
           WebView web;
                  web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                  web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                  web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                  web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                  web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


                  web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                      @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {          
                            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                             pgb.setProgress(newProgress);
                          }     
                         @Override
                         public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback)
                         {


                         //What can i do here??? so as to open gallery

                        }

                  });
web.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
```

Any ideas?